# PIXI sprite position different to location

Tags: pixi.js

*pixi-v4*

In my scene, I am rendering a sprite 'play' button, positioning it using `sprite.transform.position.x = 1760`

The texture of the sprite displays exactly where I want it, but turning the sprite into a button I can see that the hit location is a bit off. Using [PIXI Devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pixijs-devtools/aamddddknhcagpehecnhphigffljadon) makes visualising the issue easier
[image]

As you can see, the texture is positioned properly but the sprite is actually a few pixels to the right.
I've noticed that when positioning a sprite on `x = 0`, then the texture and sprite are in the same location. However, moving the sprite to a different x-location, the texture slides a bit off (More depending on how far it is from origin)

This issue isn't only for button mode - it happens to all textures / sprites. I've tried setting the anchor but the issue remains the same.

**Edit**
It's *not* got to do with resizing or scaling the renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was strangely padding - Updating the style to force the stage to stay in the center of the screen was messing with the positioning of the sprites in game.